# Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: xxx.model.Application
```

However everything looks to be properly configured.  Can anyone see if there is something I'm missing?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:/dctm/db.props"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xxxDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xxxSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="xxxDataSource"/>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>xxx.model.Application</value>
    </list>
        </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.debug_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${db.timeout}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="patiDao" class="xxx.dao.hibernate.PatiHibernateDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="xxxSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: post the code from  your `xxx.model.Applicatio`

Comment: I think jboss bundels hibernate jars as part of server, can you check if there is conflict with hibernate versions on application vs server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using JPA or just straight Hibernate?  If you're using JPA try defining a META-INF/persistence.xml where you'll define your annotated entity classes:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/MyDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>xxx.model.Application</class>
    <class>xxx.model.Class2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes />
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing `@Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COURSES")
public class Application{
  //some code
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is all done.  One weird thing I just noticed is that it runs fine in a JUnit test, but when deployed to JBoss 5.1 it gets the error.

Comment: This suggests that JBOSS isn't finding your .hbm.xml files correctly.  That message means that it can't find that file for xx.model.Application.  Check your assumptions - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: There is no hbm.xml file, it's all done in the spring config.

Comment: I doubt you are using wrong import for `@Entity`, it should be [`@Entity`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html)

Answer (score 1):

I see two reasons for this error. First if you missed the `@Entity` in `Application` class. The second one is if the `Application` class is not in build path and doesn't get deployed to JBoss.

Comment: in later case shouldn't it be a `ClassNotFoundException` ?

Comment: you may be right.. a `ClassNotFoundException` could have preceded the `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: xxx.model.Application` and the questioner didnt look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to let the *AnnotationSessionFactoryBean* find the *@Entity* classes itself (by classpath scanning), by providing a value for it's *packagesToScan* property, instead of manually specifying the classes with the *annotatedClasses* property.